# Split paragraphs into table rows

Tags: tables, titles

I am writing a class file.  I am defining a variable for my custom `\maketitle` like so:

```
\newcommand*{\comment}[1]{\def\commentname{#1}}
\comment{}
```

I want to be able to write a list of comments like so:

```
\comment{
    Comment1: this is a comment.

    Comment2: this is also a comment.

    etc.
}
```

Then I would like my `\maketitle` to form a table with each of the comments in a separate row.  The table should preferably have a dynamic number of rows so that added comments increase the size of the table.

Is this possible?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a different input syntax with each comment as a separate command rather than split paragraphs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{comment}
\def\comments{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\comment[1]{%
\stepcounter{comment}%
\def\tmp##1{\g@addto@macro\comments{Comment ##1 & #1\\}}%
\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\the\c@comment}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\comment{first thing}

\comment {second thing}

\comment {a very very liong third thing}




\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\comments
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

Or if you want explicit comment labels rather than a counter, it is a bit easier
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{comment}
\def\comments{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\comment[2]{%
\g@addto@macro\comments{Comment #1 & #2\\}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\comment{com 1}{first thing}

\comment{com B}{second thing}

\comment{comment three}{a very very liong third thing}




\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\comments
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Expanding `\thecomment` only once is not sufficient. An `\edef` is needed. Or a preposterous number of `\expandafter`s.

Comment: this looks like it is just what I want.  Any chance you could explain the comment command though? Would it be simple to add another argument to the comment which would be a version number, showing up in a different row of the table - instead of a simple counter?

Comment: i am trying just something like this:  `\def\comments{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\comment}[2]{%
\g@addto@macro\comments{#1 & #2\\}}
\makeatother` but with no luck.  i don't really understand the g@addto@macro line

Comment: That looks like it should work: I updated my answer